# Tutorials that explain boosting

Tags: machine-learning, boosting, ensemble-learning

I'm a newbie trying to learn `Boosting`. The examples I found online are quite confusing. Is there a simple tutorial somewhere that explains `Boosting` with an example?

Comment: A short note on boosting in the context of decision trees is provided in James et al. ["An Introduction to Statistical Learning"](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/ISLR%20Fourth%20Printing.pdf) p. 321-324. More detailed treatment is in Hastie et al. ["The Elements of Statistical Learning"](http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/download.html) Chapter 10.

Comment: A working guide to boosted regression trees. *Journal of Animal Ecology* often used in introductory courses

Answer (score 1):

Recommended in comments:

A short note on boosting in the context of decision trees is provided in James et al. "[An Introduction to Statistical Learning](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/ISLR%20Fourth%20Printing.pdf)" p. 321-324. More detailed treatment is in Hastie et al. "[The Elements of Statistical Learning](http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/download.html)" Chapter 10. – Richard Hardy

A working guide to boosted regression trees. Journal of Animal Ecology often used in introductory courses – charles

Comment: h/t @RichardHardy

Comment: hat tip to @charles

Answer (score 1):

[Machine Learning: Classification](https://www.coursera.org/learn/ml-classification)

This MOOC on Coursera by University of Washington has a very good and comprehensive explanation of boosting models in Week 5. They have specifically focused on Adaboost and have given a very good and easy to understand explanation of the model and the mathematics behind it. To get a glimpse of how the video is you can look at this [pdf](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse446/17wi/slides/boosting-kNNclassification-annotated.pdf) 
I also found [this article](http://blog.kaggle.com/2017/01/23/a-kaggle-master-explains-gradient-boosting/) to be a very good intuitive explanation of XGBoost.

Comment: I really wish we'd stop focusing on AdaBoost.

Comment: @MatthewDrury: What would you propose to get the basics of a reference implementation based on your experience? AnyBoost (Mason et al.), LogitBoost (Friedman), something else?

Comment: Regression boosting to minimize least squares, here's an exposition I put together for a job interview: https://github.com/madrury/boosting-presentation/blob/master/latex/presentation.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Chris' Bishop [Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387310732) has a full chapter ( Chapter 14) which addresses Bagging, boosting etc, def. worth a look, hope this helps!